# mailto and get url in same jQuery action

Tags: jquery

How can I mailto: and navigate to a URL with the same jQuery action? I want to do the following:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#foo').click(function() {
      window.location.href = 'mailto:foo@bar.com';
      window.location.href = 'bar.com';
    });
  });
</script>
```

… but the above only executes the mailto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a better way to do it, but it doesn't seem like it without opening up a new window. The method I came up with below works. Tested in Chrome.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xxv6E/

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#foo').click(function(e) {
      window.location.href = 'mailto:foo@bar.com';
      setTimeout(function(){
          window.location.href = 'bar.com';
      }, 500);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could probably create an IFRAME element on the fly with jQuery and set its `src` property to your mailto address, however I think the timeout method is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this,

```
<a href="mailto:mail@domain.com" onclick="window.location.href='np.html'">send</a>
```

Using timeout function between two calls

```
function myFunc() {
    location.href = "mailto:test@test.com&body=Hello!";
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.href = "newPage.html";
    }, 500);
}
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would change the first window.location window.open() -- that should open the mailto part in a new window and still allow the current window to change the current location.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202986/can-i-have-two-jquery-onclick-events-in-one-element)

```
$('#demo12').click(function() { 
    alert('1st click event');
    //  Add items to the cart here
});

$('#demo12').click(function() { 
    alert('2nd click event');
    //  Do something else
});
```