# onclick on Bootstrap radio button does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have declared the same structure:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" style="margin-left:50px;"> 
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input id="past5m" type="radio"> 5m
    </label> 
    <label class="btn btn-default"> 
        <input id="past1h" type="radio"> 1h
    </label>
</div>
```

which, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202986/can-i-have-two-jquery-onclick-events-in-one-element) should enable me to attach an `onclick` event by adding:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#past5m').click(function() { 
        alert('hello'); 
    });
});
```

JQuery is already included in the code.

However, when `#past5m' is pressed, nothing happens.

Can you please help me to spot the error?

Thanks.

Comment: use `$(document).ready` or `$(window).load`

Comment: Do you have jquery installed

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xpavghyb/

Answer (score 3):

You click the label, not the value. Try

```
$(window).ready(function() {

    $('#past5m').closest('label').click(function() { 
        alert('hello'); 
    });
});
```

Try it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0f4uk4/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured it out thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832568/click-event-not-firing-within-a-bootstrap-radio-button-group):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#past5m').change(function() { 
        alert('hello'); 
    });
});
```